# Using Fotorama api for follow a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

I am building a site using the Fotorama (www.fotorama.io) Jquery plugin. I have been using this code to generate custom thumbnails.
I need to somehow catch the press on the picture to go.

```
$("#fotorama_right_div").on("click", 'img', function() {    
$('#fotorama_right_div').one('fotorama:showend', function (e, fotorama) {
    console.log($(fotorama.activeFrame).attr('url'));
});});
```

But my code is not correct, I do not always get the desired picture.

How can I catch a picture and click on the option to receive data from radar images?

```
<img data-url="http:://ya.ru" src="http://s.fotorama.io/1.jpg">...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the attr method

```
$(fotorama.activeFrame).attr('url')
```

White the attribute's name is data-url

either use the data("url") method or attr("data-url")

Could you give that a try?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have found a solution.
It is necessary to pull through the object attributes "fotoram":
$('#fotorama_right_div').data('fotorama').activeFrame.url